# not to store source code in Client Pc Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

In our company we are using MS Team Foundation Server 2010. 
Is it Possible not to store source code in Client Pc?

Comment: Why do you not want to have a local working copy of your source code?

Comment: A developer has to download the source code onto their client PC in order to edit, compile, build and check-in code. Why don't you want to store the source code on the client PC?

Comment: We need that because workers copy the source code and they take the software with them when they quit job.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trust issue, not a technical issue.

Comment: I would suggest that you not employ people you do not trust.

Answer (score 0):

You could just let them RDP into machines that have clipboard paste and file-transfer disabled. You will also need to disable general internet access on those hosts to ensure they can't paste into emails etc.

Of course that would ensure you only get the sort of people you wouldn't want working on your product anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot IDisposable.